# Search for multiple words/substrings in a string using MongoDB Queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model as shown

```
[
    {"_id": "1", "Title": "boat test"},
    {"_id": "2", "Title": "mobiles and extras"}
]
```

`Query_String = "boat"` // should return [{"_id": "1", "Title": "boat test"}]

`Query_String = "boat te"` // should return [{"_id": "1", "Title": "boat test"}]

`Query_String = "mobiles"` // should return [{"_id": "2", "Title": "mobiles and extras"}]

`Query_String = "mob"` // should return [{"_id": "2", "Title": "mobiles and extras"}]

`Query_String = "boat mobile"` // should return [{"_id": "1", "Title": "boat test"}, {"_id": "2", "Title": "mobiles and extras"}]

My query is to get all products whose "Title" field has any of the words in a given Query_String

I tried this but this works for 1st case only in which Query_String is "boat"

```
const { Products } = require("../models/Products");

Products.find({
      Title: {
        $regex: `.*${Query_String}.*`,
        $options: "i",
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches,

**Using javascript RegExp:**

- split string by space and make array, map to convert string to regular express
- Try [$in Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions), To include a regular expression in an $in query expression, you can only use JavaScript regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/ ). For example:

```
let QString = Query_String.split(" ").map(s => new RegExp(s));
Products.find({
  $or: [
    { Title: { $in: QString } },
    // more fields if needed
    { Category: { $in: QString } }
  ]  
});
```

**Using `$or` conditional and `$regex`**

- split string by space and make array, map to prepare array of separate conditions
- check `$or` condition

```
let QStringTitle = Query_String.split(" ").map(s => { 
  return {
    {
      Title: {
        $regex: s,
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  };
});
let QStringCategory = Query_String.split(" ").map(s => { 
  return {
    {
      Category: {
        $regex: s,
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  };
});
Products.find({ $or: QStringTitle.concat(QStringCategory) });
```

Comment: I tried this out and it worked out prefectly fine... 


`let TitleFilter = req.body.Title.split(" ").map((s) => {
      return {
        Title: {
          $regex: s,
          $options: "i",
        },
      };
    });`

`const product = await Products.find({ $or: TitleFilter });`
// this returned output as expected
but what if I want to also check Category Field for the same query.... For ex right now I am checking Just for Title field..what if I want to check for Title and Category field both at the same time...i.e; for Multiple fields.

Comment: I have updated the answer with category condition.

Comment: I used the second approach for my problem. It works Perfectly fine. Thanks!

We can use the spread operator also here just to concat the two arars like this..
`[...TitleFilter, ...CategoryFilter]`